# Insert specific values in a dedicate column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some values:

```
['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow']
```

My view from a single table looks like this

```
ID  |  name
============
 1  |  foo
 2  |  bar
 3  |  zoo
 4  |  lou
 5  |  buu
 6  |  klu
```

The extra column "color" should have one item of the array followed by the next starting with the first item if the last has been reached:

```
ID  |  name  | color
=====================
 1  |  foo   | blue
 2  |  bar   | green
 3  |  zoo   | red
 4  |  lou   | yellow
 5  |  buu   | blue
 6  |  klu   | green
```

note that after "yellow" it starts with "blue" again

In php I would do it with a modulo operator like

```
$colors[$i % count($colors)]
```

But with SQL I have no idea how to get the current row ($i). The colors are hardcoded in the statement. Here's my "idea":

```
SELECT table.*, XXXX AS color FROM table
```

The `XXXX` should get replaced with something like `MOD($i, 4)`

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create the equivalant of a "counter table."

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Color] [nchar](10) NULL
)
```

And then fill it with the values you want.  You could create 100s of thousands of rows quite easily.

```
DECLARE @i int = 0

WHILE @i < 100
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table_1(Color)
VALUES('blue')

INSERT INTO Table_1(Color)
VALUES('green')

INSERT INTO Table_1(Color)
VALUES('red')

INSERT INTO Table_1(Color)
VALUES('yellow')

SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Then it is a simple INNER JOIN by ID.

Comment: Then I rather would go with a PHP solution, thought it was "a simple trick"

Comment: There are probably 10 different ways to do this.